# How to create mediaRecorder for video and connect to existing textureView with Camera2 Kotlin API

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, mediarecorder, android-textureview

I have a textureView initialized by:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun open_camera() {
        cameraManager.openCamera(camIdWithFlash, object: CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
                cameraDevice = camera

                capReq = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
                var surface = Surface(textureView.surfaceTexture)
                capReq.addTarget(surface)

//                captureRequest = capReq.build()


                cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(listOf(surface), object:
                    CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                        cameraCaptureSession = session
                        // Setting up capture request modifications
//                        capReq.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF)

                        cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(capReq.build(), null, null)
                    }

                    override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }

                }, handler)
            }

            override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {

            }

            override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {

            }

        }, handler)
    }
```

However I am really lost in how to create a mediaRecorder to take video and connect it with the texture view. I've tried watching tutorials but they are often really old and do not work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Declare specific variables in [`activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) and [`fragment`](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments).

```
private var mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null
private lateinit var videoFilePath: String
```

---

Initialize [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder).

```
private fun setUpMediaRecorder() {
    //mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
    mediaRecorder?.apply? {

        //setVideoSource
        //setOutputFormat
        //setOutputFile
        //setVideoEncodingBitRate
        //setVideoFrameRate
        //setVideoSize
        //setVideoEncoder

        //prepare()

    }
}
```

---

###### Use a similar guide to record video and connect to [`TextureView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView) using [`Camera2 Kotlin Api`](https://developer.android.com/training/camera2)

1. Instance the [`CameraManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager) and [`TextureView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView).
2. Check camera permissions.
3. Use [`CameraManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager) and set [`TextureView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView).
4. Instance [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) and init parameters using [`initMediaRecorder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder).
5. Create [`Surface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface) for [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) and add it as target for [`CaptureRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest).
6. Declare the fun.
7. Call [`startRecording`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) and [`stopRecording`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) functions.

---

The function has to set up [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder). [`getRotationCompensation`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685408/creating-a-firebase-vision-image-from-image-class-java-android) is a `helper function`, and you should define it like this:

```
private fun getRotationCompensation(cameraId: String, activity: Activity): Int {
    //val rotation = activity. ...
    //val sensorOrientation = getSensorOrientation

    return if (isFrontCamera(cameraId)) {
        (sensorOrientation + rotation) % 360
    } else {  // back-facing camera
        (sensorOrientation - rotation + 360) % 360
    }
}

private fun getSensorOrientation(cameraId: String): Int {
    //val characteristics = cameraManager. ...
    //return characteristics. ...
}

private fun isFrontCamera(cameraId: String): Boolean {
    //val characteristics = cameraManager. ...
    //val facing = characteristics. ...
    //return facing == CameraCharacteristics. ...
}
```

---

Create Recording function that has to start the [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) and should begin recording.

```
private fun startRecording() {
    if (mediaRecorder == null) {
        //setUpMediaRecorder()
    }

    //mediaRecorder?.start()
}
```

---

Create Stop Recording function that has to stop the [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) and reset the recording.

```
private fun stopRecording() {
    //mediaRecorder?.apply {
        //stop()
        //reset()
    }
}
```

---

Create [`open_camera`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera) fun to include [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) Callback.

```
    @SuppressLint("...permisions")
    fun open_camera() {
        cameraManager...(..., object : ...() {
            override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
                cameraDevice = camera
    
                //capReq = cameraDevice...(...camera device)
                //var surface = Surface(...)
                //capReq.addTarget(surface)
    
                // Set up MediaRecorder
                //setUpMediaRecorder()
    
                cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
                    listOf(..., ...),
                    //Create object of CameraCaptureSession
    
                            override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
                        //stopRecording()
                    }
            }, handler)
        }
    }
    }
```

---

Create a function to get file path:

```
private fun getVideoFilePath(): String {
    //val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
    //val fileName = ...
    //val storageDir = ...
    return "${storageDir?.absolutePath}/$fileName"
}
```

---

Call [`startRecording fun`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera) and call [`stopRecording fun`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera):

```
startRecording()
...
stopRecording()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really wish I could upvote you but alas I'm kind of a noob. On the initialize section how would I go about initializing the parameters?

Comment: I just edited the answer. I create a guide for this specific request. If you need additional help feel free to ask for more.

Comment: I get an error when I have the mediaRecorder stop, which I assume occurs because no mediaRecorder is actually being created. How would I go about solving/debugging that issue?